# Scrapy not fetching values from the website

Tags: python, scrapy

I have written scrapy codes before and it work as expected, but somehow in this particular 1 my logic does not work, please help me out:

My items.py:

```
import scrapy

class KohlItem(scrapy.Item):
    images=scrapy.Field()
    links=scrapy.Field()
    name=scrapy.Field()
    title=scrapy.Field()
```

My first.py:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider,Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from kohl.items import KohlItem


class FirstSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "first"
    allowed_domains = ["kohls.com"]
    start_urls = [    
        "http://www.kohls.com/catalog/mens-t-shirts-tops-tees-tops-clothing.jsp?CN=Gender:Mens+Silhouette:T-Shirts+Product:Tops%20%26%20Tees+Category:Tops+Department:Clothing&cc=mens-TN3.0-S-tshirts",
        "http://www.kohls.com/catalog/mens-t-shirts-tops-tees-tops-clothing.jsp?CN=Gender:Mens+Silhouette:T-Shirts+Product:Tops%20%26%20Tees+Category:Tops+Department:Clothing&cc=mens-TN3.0-S-tshirts&PPP=60&WS=240"]


    def parse(self, response):
        #print response.url

        kk=ItemLoader(item=KohlItem(),response=response)
        kk.add_xpath('title','//title/text()')
        kk.add_value('links',response.url)
        kk.add_xpath('images','//*[@class="pmp-hero-img"]/@src')
        print 'images ******************'
        kk.add_xpath('name','//*[@class="prod_nameBlock"]/p/text()')
        print '******************'
        return kk.load_item()
```

The output is giving me title as expected but rest values are not coming.

the above used xpaths are working fine in browser console and giving me outputs as expected.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would check is if the page is rendered using javascript or not. If it is then webdriver will help.